# Woocommerce new shop page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, pages

I would like to have a page like page.php to display the content of the shop page. How can i do it?

I copied everything from woocommerce/archive-product.php in to page.php but nothing is beeing displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Personally i would create a custom template and not use page.php and add a simply product loop

Quick break down

create new template called customshop.php

```
<?php /* Template Name: Custom Shop */ ?>
```

add your shop loop

```
<ul class="products">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 12
            );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul><!--/.products-->
```

create your new page in pages and change your template to your new page in the drop down

logic behind adding the loop as a custom template is purely for neatness and you may want a variety of custom templates and adding customshop.php means you can add lots more and you are keeping your structure neat